# Not able to play Mpeg2-ts file in Internet Explorer

Tags: html5-video, avi, mpeg, mpeg2-ts

Window media player cannot able to play "ts file format" now and i m sure which was working earlier and pretty sure there was no change in the code.

can anyone guess what will be the root cause?

```
 <object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab##version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="100%" height="500">
```

```
 <param name="animationatstart" value="true">

 <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">

 <param name="autostart" value="true">

 <param name="showcontrols" value="true">

 <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">

 <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">

 <embed src="SERVER-URL/test.ts" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="100%" height="500">
```

got the sample video from this url :http://www.dododge.net/roku/ts-samples.html

Answer (score 0):

Only Windows Media Player 12 and newer support native MPEG-TS playback.

For a complete list of formats see the Microsoft support page at:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316992